# SWbemServices.ExecQuery - "Invalid Parameter" when adding a WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, wmi, wmi-query, wql, wsh

I have the following JavaScript to execute a WMI query on a remote Windows host:

```
var wmiLocator = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.Swbemlocator");
var wmiService = wmiLocator.ConnectServer(host, "root\\cimv2", user, pass);

var items = wmiService.ExecQuery(query);

for(var e = new Enumerator(items); ! e.atEnd(); e.moveNext())
{
    WScript.StdOut.Write(e.item().GetObjectText_());
}
```

`user` and `pass` are the login credentials for the remote `host`, `query` is the WQL query to be performed.

This all works fine until I add a WHERE clause to the WQL query. For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk
```

yields the expected result, but

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3
```

will result in an "Invalid Parameter" error (wbemErrInvalidParameter / 0x80041008).

I've found numerous examples in which WHERE clauses are used, and I cannot find any info about it not being supported. Am I missing something here?

In case it is any relevant, the host executing this script is a Windows XP Professional with SP2.

Comment: How is the query string constructed? You could try a couple of things like echoing its value to see if it contains a valid query string. You could also try executing the query with wbemtest.exe.

Comment: Oh gosh, this is embarrassing... the query string was actually disrupted because of a parsing I do earlier with "equals" signs involved.

Thanks a bunch! I believe this can be closed.

Comment: Then post your solution as an answer below and mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by Helen, I am answering this myself.

The query string was changed by some parsing I did earlier in my script and became syntactically invalid, hence the invalid parameter error.